# Saving on DOSBox

Tags: dosbox, zork

I'm running ZORK.BAT on DOSBox. The problem is that whenever I want to save the game, and it asks me:

```
insert save disk then enter file name.
(Default is C:SAVE\ZORK1.DAT):
```

No matter what I wrote, it would tell me it can't find the file:

```
Unable to Access file
Failed.
```

I tried to copy a file in dos (outside game) and it wouldn't work as expected. I think maybe the DOSBox doesn't have writing permissions but I couldn't figure out how to fix this.

All the files (the ZORK1 folder) are saved in c:\OLDGAMES\ in my pc. I mounted OLDGAMES to be the c drive of the DOSBox so the directory for saving the file in the box is c:\ZORK1\SAVE\ZORK1.DAT. 
The directory and the file exists both on my computer and in the virtual box (when commanding "dir" it shows the "SAVE" folder in the list).

Comment: Where'd the game come from?  I suspect that's going to be critical information.

Comment: @Frank Required information added.

Comment: Does the C:\OLDGAMES\ZORK1\SAVE directory already exist? I wonder if it just doesn't have directory-creation privileges, but it could write to an existing directory.

Comment: Yes, it exists on my windows computer, and on dos as C:\zork1\save\
Even the ZORK1.DAT file exist.

Comment: Note that the default path it displays is a [drive-relative path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths) (no backslash after `C:`), which may cause it to resolve to something unexpected.

Comment: @Kevin I though it was weird too, but I tried many different paths and also tried to save outside the game and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating the `SAVE/ZORK1.DAT` file attributes so it is not read-only.

This fixed it for me.